# zsh: command not found: mysql. MySQL is not compatible for zsh?

Tags: mysql, macos, zsh

Isn't possible to install MySQL in zsh in macOS?

I have been trying to install MySQL on my Mac.

> zsh: command not found: mysql

Should I give up setting MySQL on zsh and try to do in bash?

---

```
% brew install mysql@5.7
```

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mysql/5.7/manifests/5.7.32-2
Already downloaded: /Users/stackover/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/abe6a0a4787f4c4bd9c6d14e27d98d868c1f0f619cbbba601e8225--mysql@5.7-5.7.32-2.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mysql/5.7/blobs/sha256:82867504
Already downloaded: /Users/stackover/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8db250bb2773af3411c71cf86232ed647cdf9366670c716c52574d--mysql@5.7--5.7.32.arm64_big_sur.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Pouring mysql@5.7--5.7.32.arm64_big_sur.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Caveats
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

mysql@5.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have mysql@5.7 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find mysql@5.7 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/include"


To have launchd start mysql@5.7 now and restart at login:
  brew services start mysql@5.7
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.32: 319 files, 233.7MB
stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ %   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ % myql --version
zsh: command not found: myql
stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ % mysql --version
zsh: command not found: mysql
stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ %   export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/lib"
stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ %   export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/include"
```

```
 echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/lib"

I checked if it installed:

```
stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ % mysql --version
```

but

```
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

I also tried this:

```
stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ % mysql -uroot
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

Comment: What happens if you run the command `(PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH; mysql --version)`, including the parenthesis?

Comment: "install mysql in zsh" - what does that mean? How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ %   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
> stackover@stackoverjunoMacBook-Air ~ % mysql --version
> zsh: command not found: mysql
> ```

Your shell does not automagically pick up new executables from your `$path`. For the shell to find the new executable, you will need to

- rebuild your shell’s command lookup table with

  ```
  hash -fr
  ```
- restart your shell with

  ```
  exec zsh
  ```
- or open a new tab in your terminal.

Comment: Or `. ~/.zshrc`

Comment: No. It's almost always a **bad idea** to run `. ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`. It may result in random errors, misbehaving code and progressive slowdown of Zsh. If you've made changes to `~/.zshrc` or to files sourced by it, restart Zsh to apply them.

Comment: Isn't adding the install package to the path the whole point of a package manager? Why doesn't homebrew just do this for you???

Comment: @Scorb Homebrew cannot actually do that for your shell, because it runs as subprocess of your shell and not _in_ your shell (like a native function or a `source`d script would). However, you can tell your shell to refresh its command lookup table. I’ve added this option to my answer.